# Snap an inset face to edge instead of in the center?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm insetting a face and I want it to inset towards an edge instead of just insetting in the center. I know there is a way to achieve this. **How do I do this?**
Photo 1: default inset
Photo 2: Desired result (in this instance I just movied the insetted face down after inset)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works when there are open edges.
You need to remove some faces to make it work.

1. Remove the bottom face
2. Inset and uncheck *Boundary*
3. Done

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I kept on hitting "B" but it wouldn't work lol I didn't realize that it had to be an open face.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)